# ruby on rails: no routes using edit_path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I have two different controllers I got from rails generate, and each controller has index, edit, update, destroy, etc...

Now I'm trying to relate these two controllers (lists and ideas). I have this loop in my lists -> show page

```
<% @list.ideas.each do |idea| %>
  <div>
    <div class="list_idea_desc"><%= idea.description %></div>
    <div><%= link_to 'Show', idea %></div>
    <div><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_idea_path(idea) %></div>
    <div><%= link_to 'Destroy', idea, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm trying to get the `edit_idea_path` to work, but it gives me error

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"ideas", 
:id=>#<Idea id: nil, name: nil, description: nil, picture: nil, 
created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, list_id: 2>}
```

Any idea how I can use the two different controllers? Does this give enough information?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `Idea` instance doesn't have an ID (`:id=>#<Idea id: nil...`), so the router can't generate a route for it. Make sure your Ideas are saved before attempting to generate yours for them.

Also, not directly related to the problem, but you can just use `link_to "Edit", [:edit, idea]` to have it infer the route based on the class of `idea`.

Comment: are you saying because in my Idea controller I have a method `def edit` and under that I have `@idea = Idea.find(params[:id])` where its looking for a `params[:id]`? But within my idea.description, there are a table already that should be related to the `list`? I'm sorry, maybe I'm just not understanding rails, do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

check your routes.rb file as you are using RESTful routing

and if not help, paste the routes code here

Comment: I have a `edit_idea` `GET` `/ideas/:id/edit(.:format)` `ideas#edit`